# switch case in c, default before case

Tags: c, switch-statement

I was trying this :

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
int i = 2;
switch(i) {
    default:{
        printf("Hi\n");}
    case 1:
        printf("Hi1\n");
    case 2:
        printf("Hi2\n");
}
}
```

output is "Hi2" as expected, however if i = 3,

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
int i = 3;
switch(i) {
    default:{
        printf("Hi\n");}
    case 1:
        printf("Hi1\n");
    case 2:
        printf("Hi2\n");
    }
}
```

Output is 
    "Hi"
    "Hi1"
    "Hi2"

How does program enter other cases which do not match? I know putting break in default would solve this.

Why this behavior? Is there anything mentioned in C specification for this?

Comment: Give me a `break`, will you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C (and many other languages) the cases are simply labels that get 'jumped' to.  Once execution starts in a selected case, it flows just like normal.  If you want execution to 'stop' at the end of a case 'block' you have to use the `break` statement (or some other flow control statement):

```
switch(i) {
    default:{
        printf("Hi\n");}
        break;
    case 1:
        printf("Hi1\n");
        break;
    case 2:
        printf("Hi2\n");
        break;
    }
}
```

For whatever it's worth, in my opinion this is was an unfortunate decision made by the language designers since falling through to the next case after execution one or more statements in a case are executed is very, very rarely desired. However, that's the way the language works.

C# addresses this by making it so falling out of a case is illegal - some sort of explicit flow control (a `break` or a `goto`) is required at the end of a sequence of of statements in a case (unless it's the last case in the switch).

Answer (score 2):

This is because the code steps through each instruction unless explicitly stated not to.

In a `switch() { }`, you must be explicit.

Think about the instructions backed by this C. It would be a jump table. Without break, there would be no jump beneath each branch to go *after* the switch case.

Answer (score 0):

Complementing @alex, try this.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
  int i = 2;
    switch(i) {
        default:{
          printf("Hi\n");}
        case 2:
          printf("Hi2\n");    
        case 1:
          printf("Hi1\n");
    }
}
```